# Implementation of DDA Line Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics

I have tested all the cases of how a line could be

1. vertically
2. horizontally
3. has a slope that's positive or less than 1

The function works, but I would like it reviewed, such as if there are overflows, etc.

```
// Draw line using DDA Algorithm
void Graphics::DrawLine( int x1, int y1, int x2, int y2, Color&color )
{

    float xdiff = x1-x2; 
    float ydiff = y1-y2; 
    int slope  = 1; 
    if ( y1  == y2  )
    {
        slope = 0;
    }
    else if (  x1 == x2 )
    {
        slope = 2; // vertical lines have no slopes...
    }
    else
    {
        slope = (int)xdiff/ydiff; 
    }

    if ( slope <= 1 )
    {    
        int startx = 0;
        int endx   = 0;
        if ( x1 > x2 )
        {
            startx = x2;
            endx   = x1;
        }
        else 
        {
            startx = x1;
            endx   = x2;
        }

        float y = y1; // initial value
        for(int x = startx; x <= endx; x++)
        {
            y += slope;
            DrawPixel(x, (int)abs(y), color);
        }
    }

    else if ( slope > 1 )
    {
        float x = x1; // initial value
        for(int y = y1;y <= y2; y++)
        {
            x += 1/slope;
            DrawPixel((int)x, y, color);
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bresenham's_line_algorithm

Comment: Question is almost year old. Working code for him (with flaws). I do **not** see any reason why we should close this question now as answer is also provided and accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some flaws in the current algorithm.

- `xdiff` will have a roundoff error if `x1-x2` is large in magnitude, likewise for the `y` variables.
- `slope` is set to `1` for no reason, and then immediately reinitialized to something else.
- `slope` is restricted to an integer, when most slopes will not be integral.
- It's impossible to justify setting the slope of a vertical line to `2`. There are slopes greater than `2` that are not vertical lines.
- In the line `slope = (int)xdiff/ydiff;`, casting is higher precedence than division, so this will first cast `xdiff` to an `int`, overflowing if `xdiff > MAXINT`, throwing away the fractional part if there is one, then dividing this `int` by `ydiff`. The odds of this being the actual slope are very small.
- `startx` and `endx` are initialized to `0` for no reason, then immediately reinitialized to somethiing else.
- Roundoff errors will accumulate as you repeatedly add `slope` to `y` (or `1/slope` to x).
- What's the justification for the `abs(y)`? If `y` changes sign in the range, this will cause a kink in the line. Similarly for `x`.

Answer (score 1):

This makes no sense.  The `slope` must be an `int` such as 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, … but a vertical line is treated as a line of slope 2?  How is that accurate at all?

Comment: How would I solve it ? Vertical lines have no slope at all.

Comment: [DDA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_differential_analyzer_\(graphics_algorithm\)). Make two cases. If `abs(ydiff) <= abs(xdiff)`, then proceed as usual with `slope = ydiff / xdiff` and iterate along the x-axis pixels, plotting y. Otherwise, reverse the roles of the x and y axes — compute an `inverseSlope = xdiff / ydiff` and iterate along the y-axis pixels, plotting x.

Comment: I have the book Fundamental of computer graphics, by peter shirely, but it doesn't really explain the algorithms really well, can you suggest a better reference for software rasterizations ?

Comment: Go from a slope to a dx and a dy, with either the dx or dy being 1.